# Can't upload file to Google Drive from service account

Tags: google-apps, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a file to google drive using google service account.

**Driver Service**

```
public static Drive getDriveService(String secretKeyFile) throws GeneralSecurityException,
    IOException, URISyntaxException {
  HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
          new java.io.File(secretKeyFile))
      .build();
  Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
      .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).setApplicationName("appl name").build();
  return service;
}
```

**Insert File**

```
 private static File insertFile(Drive service, String title, String description,String mimeType, String filename) {
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(title);
    body.setDescription(description);
    body.setMimeType(mimeType);

    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, fileContent);
    try {
      File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
      return file;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

**Main Method**

```
     Drive service=null;
        try {
            String secretFile= "somedigit-privatekey.p12";
            service = getDriveService(secretFile);
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    File insertFile = insertFile(service, "test title", "File description", "text/plain", "c:\\test.txt");
List list = service.files().list();
System.out.println("Files Id : "+insertFile.getId());
System.out.println("Count Files : "+list.size());
```

Now, my questions is :

- How and where can i check that file was uploaded?
- Why it returns the file ID but list.size() is zero.
- It returns the download link also but when i paste that link in
  browser it doesn't download any file.

Comment: It's better to start individual topics for each question. I'm going to provide an answer below though.

Comment: You could do this?? I have the same problem :(

Comment: My question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146712/upload-file-to-google-drive-in-java-without-oauth

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a listing request but not executing it. Use `execute` method to make the request:

```
service.files().list().execute();
```

If you paste the download link into the browser, it will respond with 401, because your download request should also contain a valid Authorization header. Use the following snippet to download the file programmatically.

```
HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl())).execute();
InputStream stream = resp.getContent();
```

`stream` is an input stream for the file content.

Or add an `Authorization: Bearer <access token>` to the request you're making elsewhere.